# JSP Combo box getting wrong value

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am populating the combo box using data from db. Also i am checking the default n setting it as selected.

```
<select name="managerID">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
        <option value="${employee.id}" <c:if test="${edit.managerId == employee.id}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}, ${employee.email}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

the problem is that when i submit i always get the default value and not the user selected one.

Comment: Check the rendered html, what are some of the values for `employee.id`?

Comment: here is the rendered page source.

<select name="managerID">
 <option value="0">None</option>
      
 <option value="1" selected='selected'>Apurba Nath, apurba.n@imaginea.com</option>
      
 <option value="5" >Chandra Singh, chandra.singh@imaginea.com</option>
      
</select>

Comment: And, by default, do you mean the one where `edit.managerId == employee.id`?

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Answer (score 0):

hes sorry to have troubled you I found what was wrong with the code.
I rechecked the code there was a hidden field with name managerID and it contained the default value.